# How to user GoogleAPI Client in Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-googleapiclient

I can't use Google API Client in Fragment.

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_case_summary, container, false);

        initView(rootView);
        return rootView;

      if(mGoogleApiClient==null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
         }
```

it shows Error :
[image]

Comment: "unreachable statement". You did not research this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switch the return statement and the google API client initialization:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_case_summary, container, false);

    initView(rootView);

    if(mGoogleApiClient==null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

The return statement should always be the last line in your methods.